# PHP POST form without clicking

Tags: php, javascript, forms, paypal, submit

I'm preparing my paypal system and have a separate page that forwards the user to paypal. This page currently creates a form with all the needed hidden fields and then submits itself using

```
<body onload="form1.submit()">
```

However, when Javascript is not activated, the user gets stuck at this page.

What other method could I possibly use directly in PHP to solve this problem?

Comment: If JavaScript is disabled, you're completely out of luck, I think.

Comment: Who is it that disables JavaScript nowadays? Are there still people for whom we need to worry about "web-safe colors" too?

Comment: Yep. PHP is a server-side language, so it cannot manipulate browser events other than sending headers.. And unfortunately, sending any type of header isn't going to help you solve this problem. For that, you'll need JS to be enabled.

Comment: @Pointy Corporate IT policies

Comment: @Pointy: Unfortunately, if you want your website to be 100% compatible, yes you do. Companies especially are really sticky when it comes to upgrades, and I know of a few local ones whose employees are still suffering with IE5. But to reach *most* of your audience, these things aren't a big worry.

Comment: @onteria_ fair enough, but are people suffering under such a regime really the sort of people who should be buying things with PayPal at work?

Comment: @Pointy - Absolutely! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do the relevant request in PHP, for example using the curl binding.

Comment: decent curl tutorial here:[http://phpsense.com/php/submitting-forms-using-php-curl.html](http://phpsense.com/php/submitting-forms-using-php-curl.html)

Comment: I have not tried if this works with Paypal but do you happen to know if I can also redirect the user using cURL instead of retrieving the result and displaying it?

Comment: @Frank Vilea curl's only good for communicating with other sites, like PayPal. You want to look at response from PayPal, then redirect to appropriate page using `header("Location: full-url-of-page-to-redirect-to");`

Answer (score 1):

PHP uses the [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) directive, in which you can forward someone to another url. Not sure about your other information. If PayPal allows that to be sent in the GET string, this could work for you. If it has to be POST, then you're probably out of luck.

Or, you can use the [`cURL`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) library if PayPal returns a url for you to forward the user to.

Another option may be to allow the user to physically click the submit button for the form, and use JS to hide the form itself or something.

Comment: Thanks Jared, I think Paypal won't allow GET requests. cURL looks promising though. I already asked in the comment section of Waldheinz answer if it is also possible to redirect users instead of just retrieving the response data when using cURL for a POST request.

Comment: @Franke Vilea - As I mention, if PayPal returns a url from the cURL session (cURL acts as a proxy for a web browser), then yes, you could use cURL. Otherwise, where would you send them?

Answer (score 0):

PHP runs on your server, so without an intermediate language (like JavaScript), you are out of luck.

When you view a PHP page, the PHP engine runs the code, gets the output, and serves a plain ol' HTML page to the user. The user never interacts directly with the PHP code, only with the output.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated before, you can fall back on a header() redirect with GET parameters.

```
header('Location: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=youremail@example.com&amount=1&currency_code=USD');
```

Just append the URL with any parameters you need in name=value pair format, a list of which you can find here: https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables

Answer (score 0):

Why not just provide a more manual solution for users with Javascript disabled?

E.g. if the user has Javascript disabled, just show a submit button where they can manually move themselves along to PayPal?

Presumably, users with Javascript disabled are somewhat accustomed to a lower quality of service across the web.